# SSRS matrix columns disappearing with cross join

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I'm creating a fairly simple matrix report with SSRS and columns with no values are disappearing. I've read that cross join can be used to solve this issue but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Oracle SQL original query:

```
SELECT 
    C250_INT_EVENTNR,   
    C250_KEYCODE,
    c250_desc,
    c250_mod_user,
    c250_mod_date,
    c251_desc,
    c251_valuenew,
    c251_valueold,
    C251_SUPPLIER
FROM
    user.t250 a 
INNER JOIN
    wawiadm.t251 b ON b.C251_INT_EVENTNR = C250_INT_EVENTNR
WHERE
    c250_mod_date >= :date
    AND c251_desc IN ('Rcv Temp Min', ('Rcv Temp Max'));
```

Cross joined:

```
    select * from 
    (SELECT 
    C250_INT_EVENTNR,
    C250_KEYCODE,
    c250_desc,
    c250_mod_user,
    c250_mod_date,
    c251_desc,
    c251_valuenew,
    c251_valueold,
    C251_SUPPLIER

    from user.t250 a 

    inner join wawiadm.t251 b on b.C251_INT_EVENTNR = C250_INT_EVENTNR

    where c250_mod_date >= :date
    and c251_desc in 
    ('Rcv Temp Min', ('Rcv Temp Max'))
    
    order by c250_mod_date desc)

    cross join 
    (select distinct c251_desc from user.t251
 
    where 
    c251_desc in 
    ('Rcv Temp Min', ('Rcv Temp Max'))
    )
```

Am I doing something wrong here? It should keep the columns even if values are empty.

Thank you!

Comment: You first need to check if your query returns the results you expect. Does it contain every value in the column that you are using as a column group in SSRS. If it does then it should work. Typically, I don't cross join. I create a distinct list of the column I wan to always include, then I do a `SELECT FROM` this distinct list and then `LEFT JOIN` to my base data.

Comment: Thank you, Alan, could you provide a simple example of a distinct list with a left join in oracle sql that you use? I'll try to replicate that. Thanks!

Comment: I'll try to do this later, I've never used Oracle but I'm sure it can't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick dbfiddle that tries to demo the idea.

It might not be very elegant as I've never touched Oracle in my life but it does what's expected.

https://dbfiddle.uk/wkEX220m

You can run the code from there and see what results you get.

Here's the code in case the dbfiddle disappears

```
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE product_sales (
  product_name VARCHAR2(100),
  quantity NUMBER,
  sales_year NUMBER
);
```

```
INSERT ALL 
INTO product_sales (product_name, quantity, sales_year) VALUES ('Product A', 10, 2021)
INTO product_sales (product_name, quantity, sales_year) VALUES ('Product A', 15, 2022)
INTO product_sales (product_name, quantity, sales_year) VALUES ('Product A', 20, 2023)
INTO product_sales (product_name, quantity, sales_year) VALUES ('Product B', 5, 2022)
INTO product_sales (product_name, quantity, sales_year) VALUES ('Product B', 8, 2023)
INTO product_sales (product_name, quantity, sales_year) VALUES ('Product B', 12, 2024)
INTO product_sales (product_name, quantity, sales_year) VALUES ('Product C', 15, 2021)
INTO product_sales (product_name, quantity, sales_year) VALUES ('Product C', 25, 2022)
INTO product_sales (product_name, quantity, sales_year) VALUES ('Product C', 30, 2023)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

```
-- Show distinct list of years, for illustration
SELECT DISTINCT sales_year
FROM product_sales;
```

| SALES_YEAR |
| --- |
| 2021 |
| 2022 |
| 2023 |
| 2024 |

```
-- SELECT from our distinct list of years
-- LEFT join to whatever query you currently have, 
--   in this case it's just a simple query that filters out Product B
--   (as Product B is the only one that has 2024 data)
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT sales_year FROM product_sales) y
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_sales WHERE product_name <> 'Product B') s on y.sales_year = s.sales_year
  ;
```

| SALES_YEAR | PRODUCT_NAME | QUANTITY | SALES_YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Product A | 10 | 2021 |
| 2022 | Product A | 15 | 2022 |
| 2023 | Product A | 20 | 2023 |
| 2021 | Product C | 15 | 2021 |
| 2022 | Product C | 25 | 2022 |
| 2023 | Product C | 30 | 2023 |
| 2024 | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_y3Bb0G_)

As you can see, the year 2024 is still present, even though there is no data associated with it.